# Extending section title over margins and odd/even not working with fancyhdr

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, marginnote

I am working with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside=semi]{article}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*****************Margins and MarginNotes******************

\usepackage[top=2.8cm, bottom=2.8cm,outer=7cm, inner=1.75cm, marginparwidth=4.25cm, marginparsep=0.75cm]{geometry}

%*******************Header & Footer***********************
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footnotesize UNIT TITLE}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

%***********************Document*******************
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily \bf \Large}{}{0em}
{%
\begingroup
  \color{gray!30}%
  \titleline{\leaders\hrule height 1.75em \hskip 4pt plus 1.2 fill \kern 0pt\relax}%
\endgroup\vskip-1.323em\hskip0.5em\sffamily \thesection\hskip1em#1
\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[12]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[8]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[7]\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[7]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

This produces an article with a specific style of section title. My questions are:
1.) How can I adjust the width of the grey box behind a section title, so that it extends over the margin notes?

2.) Is there a reason why, despite specifying LO, RE for the headings they still only appear on the left hand side, despite a page being odd or even? I'd like to have the UNIT title header on the left for odd pages and on the right for even pages.

Comment: Regarding your second question: If you look into the logfile, you will see the warning that `twoside=semi` has been ignored, since there is no such option for the `article` class. And for onesided documents there are only odd pages as far as the page style is concerned. If you use the option `twoside`, you have both types of headings, but you will have to adapt the margins via the `geometry` package.

Comment: Thanks, what about the first question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `twoside=semi` option for article.

You can emulate two sided printing (for alternating headers) by using the left and right fields.

I have also simplified the definition for the gray bar underneath the section title. Don't forget to set `headheight`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*****************Margins and MarginNotes******************

\usepackage[
  top=2.8cm,
  bottom=2.8cm,
  outer=7cm,
  inner=1.75cm,
  marginparwidth=4.25cm,
  marginparsep=0.75cm,
  headheight=13.6pt,
  %showframe,% remove for production version
]{geometry}

%*******************Header & Footer***********************
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyhead[L]{\ifodd\value{page}\footnotesize UNIT TITLE\fi}
\fancyhead[R]{\ifodd\value{page}\else\footnotesize UNIT TITLE\fi}
\fancyfoot[L]{\ifodd\value{page}\thepage\fi}
\fancyfoot[R]{\ifodd\value{page}\else\thepage\fi}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%***********************Document*******************
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\graybackground}

\newcommand{\graybackground}[1]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \colorbox{gray!30}{%
      \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}{
        \vspace{3pt}
        #1\par
        \vspace{3pt}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

some text to get a page
\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
\kant[12]
\marginpar{\sloppy The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[8]
\marginpar{\sloppy The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[7]\marginpar{\sloppy The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\section{Section 2}
\kant[7]
\marginpar{\sloppy The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer that gives a complete solution because it is not clear which aspects of your layout you want to keep and which to drop; keeping all of them is probably not what you really want.

Regarding your first question, define the titleline as

```
\titleline{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\headwidth}{1.75em}}}
```

Then the gray bar will extend to the border of the margin. However, as you see below, it collides with the comments in the margin, so it may be better to confine the bar to the text area, or to have no comments in the margin.

Regarding your second question, note that the log file contains a warning that `twoside=semi` has been ignored, since there is no such option for the article class. And for one-sided documents there are only odd pages as far as the page style is concerned. If you use the option `twoside`, you have both types of headings, but you will have to adapt the margins via the geometry package. Moreover, in this case the margin comments will also jump.

In the code below, I have included the line

```
\usepackage{showframe}
```

to show the page layout. Remove it for the final document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*****************Margins and MarginNotes******************

\usepackage[top=2.8cm, bottom=2.8cm,outer=7cm, inner=1.75cm, marginparwidth=4.25cm, marginparsep=0.75cm]{geometry}

%*******************Header & Footer***********************
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footnotesize UNIT TITLE}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}

%***********************Document*******************
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily \bf \Large}{}{0em}
{%
\begingroup
  \color{gray!30}%
  \titleline{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\headwidth}{1.75em}}}%
\endgroup\vskip-1.323em\hskip0.5em\sffamily \thesection\hskip1em#1
\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[12] \marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the
  objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of,
  certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[8] \marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the
  objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of,
  certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[7]\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the
  objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of,
  certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[7] \marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the
  objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of,
  certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's excellent. Regarding the second point, I would've liked to have all the margins on the right, but still have the headers alternative from left to right depending on whether the page is odd or even. I'm not fussed as to what the document class is. I tried scrbook as well but this did not give the effect that I'm after.

Comment: @wrb98 What's your plan regarding collisions of margin notes with the gray bar?

Comment: I won't use margin notes near to grey bars. It's mainly the second point now that I wish to focus on.

Comment: if you could amend your code in any way to allow the page headers/footers to stretch to the edge of the margins, whilst alternating depending on the odd/even page then your answer would be perfect.